# VBA Excel .FindNext Ошибка "Невозможно получить свойство FindNext класса Range"

Tags: excel, vba

```
For ordinate = 1 To posStr
    Range("A" & ordinate).Select
    mWord = ActiveCell.value
    title1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).value
    Range("F2").value = title1
    Range("F3").value = mWord
    With Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A125")
        Set fcell = .Find(mWord, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        If Not fcell Is Nothing Then
            firstResult = fcell.Address
            Do
                cFound = fcell.Address
                Range(cFound).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
                title2 = ActiveCell.value
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
                If title1 = title2 Then
                    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                Set fcell = .FindNext(fcell)
            Loop While Not fcell Is Nothing And fcell.Address <> firstResult
            ordinate = ordinate + 1
        End If
    End With
Next ordinate
```

Выше представлен фрагмент кода, возвращающий ошибку. В теории всё должно работать. В другом скрипте `.FindNext` тоже работает в том же виде. Не могу понять, в чём моя ошибка.

Ниже вариант, в котором всё работает

```
For ordinate = 3 To 38
    Range("F" & ordinate).Select
    mWord = ActiveCell.value
    With Worksheets(1).Range("G1:G10000")
    Set fcell = .Find(mWord, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not fcell Is Nothing Then
        firstResult = fcell.Address
        Do
             rCopy = fcell.Row
              Rows(rCopy).Select
              Selection.Copy

              ActiveSheet.Next.Select
              Range("A1").Select
                 For d = 1 To 10000
                      If ActiveCell.value > 2 Then ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select Else: Exit For
                      d = d + 1
                 Next d
                   ActiveSheet.Paste
                   ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
               Set fcell = .FindNext(fcell)
            Loop While Not fcell Is Nothing And fcell.Address <> firstResult
          ordinate = ordinate + 1
      End If
    End With
Next ordinate
```

Comment: *В другом скрипте .FindNext тоже работает в том же виде.* Тоже в With блоке неактивного листа?

Comment: Это активный лист. Первый поиск работает нормально.

Comment: *Это активный лист.* Worksheets(2) == ActiveSheet? Тогда не понимаю, почему блок With начинается не с начала цикла (а то и обрамляет его).

Comment: Он внутри цикла For с итератором ordinate. А внутри вложен цикл Do While

Comment: То есть, мне нужно, чтобы он находил значение, а потом запускал цикл. Конкретно в таком же виде, это работает в другом скрипте. Разница только в действиях внутри цикла Do While.

Comment: Зачем  *With*  в цикле? Это нужно было поместить перед  запуском первого цикла. Но это общее замечание. А по вопросу - нужно описывать не путь решения. а саму задачу. Тогда и помощь эффективнее. Пишете , что ".FindNext Ошибка", и тут же - "Разница только в действиях внутри цикла Do While". Но цикл - после .FindNext... Так где ошибка?

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, где ошибка. Добавил к вопросу вариант, в котором всё работает.

Comment: По вопросу об ошибке: Вы написали, что ошибка *.FindNext*, далее пишете,что виноват оператор *Do While* .===*нужно описывать не путь решения, а саму задачу*. Что хотите получить?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы он искал вхождения содержимого ячейки в столбце А, сравнивал содержимое `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6)`, и если равно, удалял найденную строку.